# Image Resampling: white background

Tags: silverstripe

I took over a Silverstripe project, so im quite new.

The end comsumer mention that the white background is not renderd white. He is right.

After the resampling the white background contains some #fefefe-pixels.
Is there a way to fix that? 
The images on the demo page contains the same effect: https://demo.silverstripe.org/assets/Uploads/_resampled/ResizedImage600278-community.png

The project uses Silverstripe 3.7

Comment: Can you please share the code you're using to generate the resampled images?

Comment: It looks like this may be an issue with the PHP GD image library: https://github.com/libgd/libgd/issues/99

Comment: For rendering I use $Fill(760,760) nothing else.